# how to find if all elements in a subset of a data.frame row are TRUE

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with a block of columns that are logicals, e.g.

```
> tmp <- data.frame(a=c(13, 23, 52),
+                   b=c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE),
+                   c=c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),
+                   d=c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE))
> tmp
   a     b     c    d
1 13  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
2 23 FALSE  TRUE TRUE
3 52  TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

I'd like to compute a summary column (say: e) that is a  logical `AND` over the whole range of logical columns. In other words, for a given row, if all b:d are `TRUE`, then e would be `TRUE`; if any b:d are `FALSE`, then e would be `FALSE`.

My expected result is:

```
> tmp
   a     b     c    d     e
1 13  TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
2 23 FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE
3 52  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

I want to indicate the range of columns by indices, as I have a bunch of columns, and the names are cumbersome. The following code works, but i'd rather use a vectorized approach to improve performance.

```
> tmp$e <- NA
> for(i in 1:nrow(tmp)){
+     tmp[i,"e"] <- all(tmp[i,2:(ncol(tmp)-1)]==TRUE)
+ }
> tmp
   a     b     c    d     e
1 13  TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
2 23 FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE
3 52  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

Any way to do this without using a `for` loop to step through the rows of the data.frame?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` to loop over rows... and some fancy footwork to make it quasi-automated:

```
# identify the logical columns
boolCols <- sapply(tmp, is.logical)
# sum each row of the logical columns and
# compare to the total number of logical columns
tmp$e <- rowSums(tmp[,boolCols]) == sum(boolCols)
```

Comment: Nice! Computing a sum had occurred to me, but I hadn't thought about `rowSums` to stay within the row. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By using rowSums in ifelse statement, in one go it can be acheived:

```
tmp$e <- ifelse(rowSums(tmp[,2:4] == T) == 3, T, F)
```